# Linux shell script in importing csv data file to DB2

Tags: linux, csv, import, db2

I am new to Linux and would like to seek for your help. The task is to import csv data to DB2. It is in shell script, and on scheduled run. The file has a header that is why I used skipcount 1. Delimiter is comma so since it is the default one, I did not include COLDEL.

1. Can you help me troubleshoot as to why upon running the script, we got the error below? I am using **IMPORT** and **INSERT_UPDATE** because I learned that the **LOAD** method deletes the whole contents of the table before importing the data from CSV file. The existing data in the table should not be deleted. Records will only be updated if there are changes from the CSV file, otherwise, should create a new record.
2. I am looking at which **METHOD** should be used in getting the specific values from the CSV file and currently I am using **METHOD P**. I am not so sure with regards to numbering inside its parameter, does it signify how many columns are there to be accessed, and should tally with the ones I am importing from the file?

Below is the script snippet:

```
db2 connect to MYDB user $USERID using $PASSWORD

LOGFILE=/load/log/MYDBLog.txt

if [ -f /load/data/CUST_GRP.csv ]; then
db2 "import from /load/data/CUST_GRP.csv of del skipcount 1 modified by usedefaults METHOD P(1,2,3,4,5)
messages $LOGFILE
insert_update into myuser.CUST(NUM_ID,NUM_GRP,NUM_TEAM,NUM_LG,NUM_STATUS)";
else echo "/load/data/CUST_GRP.csv file not found." >> $LOGFILE;
fi

if [ -f /load/data/CUST_GRP.csv ]; then
db2 "import from /load/data/CUST_GRP.csv of del skipcount 1 modified by dateformat=\"YYYY-MM-DD\" timeformat=\"HH:MM:SS\" usedefaults METHOD P(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
messages $LOGFILE
insert_update into myuser.MY_CUST(NUM_CUST,DTE_START,TME_START,NUM_CUST_CLSFCN,DTE_END,TME_END,NUM_CUST_TYPE)";
else echo "/load/data/CUST_GRP.csv file not found." >> $LOGFILE;
fi
```

**The error I am encountering is this:**

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "modified" was found following "<identifier>".
Expected tokens may include:  "INSERT".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can’t place clauses in the arbitrary order in the [IMPORT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html) command.
Place the `skipcount 1` clause before `messages`.

[LOAD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html) command can either `INSERT` new portion of data or `REPLACE` the table contents emptying it at the beginning.